# Get Event Color with Google Calendar API PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am new with php and html and my english is not the best, so please be kind with me :)
I get my events with:

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents($hbCalId, $optParams);
```

When i print them on my Website, following is displayed:

> array(1) { [0]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#45 (60) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(29) "Google_Service_Calendar_Event" ["collection_key":protected]=> string(10) "recurrence" ["anyoneCanAddSelf"]=> NULL ["attachmentsType":protected]=> string(39) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttachment" ["attachmentsDataType":protected]=> string(5) "array" ["attendeesType":protected]=> string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee" ["attendeesDataType":protected]=> string(5) "array" ["attendeesOmitted"]=> NULL **["colorId"]=> string(2) "11"** ["conferenceDataType":protected]=> string(38) "Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData" ["conferenceDataDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["created"]=> string(24) "2020-10-20T17:33:54.000Z" ["creatorType":protected]=> string(36) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator" ["creatorDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> NULL ["endType":protected]=> string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime" ["endDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["endTimeUnspecified"]=> NULL ["etag"]=> string(18) ""3206430469008000"" ["extendedPropertiesType":protected]=> string(47) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties" ["extendedPropertiesDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["gadgetType":protected]=> string(35) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventGadget" ["gadgetDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["guestsCanInviteOthers"]=> NULL ["guestsCanModify"]=> NULL ["guestsCanSeeOtherGuests"]=> NULL ["hangoutLink"]=> NULL ["htmlLink"]=> string(116) "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MDByczQydnM5MXF1bHFwNzBiajFuc21icTEgYmdxOXA1cHFhcjA1cThlaDFjMDlib2RhcmNAZw" ["iCalUID"]=> string(37) "00rs42vs91qulqp70bj1nsmbq1@google.com" ["id"]=> string(26) "00rs42vs91qulqp70bj1nsmbq1" ["kind"]=> string(14) "calendar#event" ["location"]=> NULL ["locked"]=> NULL ["organizerType":protected]=> string(38) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer" ["organizerDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["originalStartTimeType":protected]=> string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime" ["originalStartTimeDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["privateCopy"]=> NULL ["recurrence"]=> NULL ["recurringEventId"]=> NULL ["remindersType":protected]=> string(38) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders" ["remindersDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["sequence"]=> int(0) ["sourceType":protected]=> string(35) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventSource" ["sourceDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["startType":protected]=> string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime" ["startDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(9) "confirmed" ["summary"]=> string(10) "Test Event" ["transparency"]=> NULL ["updated"]=> string(24) "2020-10-20T17:33:54.504Z" ["visibility"]=> NULL ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } ["creator"]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#46 (8) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(36) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator" ["displayName"]=> NULL ["email"]=> string(17) "youth@feggwatt.ch" ["id"]=> NULL ["self"]=> NULL ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["organizer"]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#47 (8) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(38) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer" ["displayName"]=> string(8) "HomeBase" ["email"]=> string(52) "bgq9p5pqar05q8eh1c09bodarc@group.calendar.google.com" ["id"]=> NULL ["self"]=> bool(true) ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["start"]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#48 (7) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime" ["date"]=> NULL ["dateTime"]=> string(25) "2020-10-21T10:00:00+02:00" ["timeZone"]=> NULL ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["end"]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#49 (7) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime" ["date"]=> NULL ["dateTime"]=> string(25) "2020-10-21T10:30:00+02:00" ["timeZone"]=> NULL ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["reminders"]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#50 (8) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(38) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders" ["collection_key":protected]=> string(9) "overrides" ["overridesType":protected]=> string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder" ["overridesDataType":protected]=> string(5) "array" ["useDefault"]=> bool(true) ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } } }

The only thing i want to read out is the "colorId". How do I read out this colorId from this array?

Many thanks for every answer!

Comment: `echo $events[0]["colorId"]`?

Comment: then comes an error: 0 - Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array

Comment: I just found out something. It has problems with session variables. I copied the array into a session variable and reloaded the page. And after that it has some problems with the classes. As you can see above: __PHP_Incomplete_Class...

Comment: Can you please provide your full code up to this point? The auth and the API call?